# how do I acces express params in my react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I'm trying to create a React application using Express as a back-end

I have this route set up in express

```
 app.get('/manage/:id', (req, res) => {
    // redirect to react application
 });
```

I want to be able to make my React component get data from my database (to then use it), but I need the id for that.

Any suggestions on how I can access the :id in my React component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the URL from the window.location object and parse it:

UPDATE: `window.location.pathname.split('/').reverse()[0]`

Comment: This returns the full `manage/154981873` , is there any way to just get the number or is using substring the only way?